# TYPO3: Is it possible to migrate single news from 1.4.0 to 6.3.0

Tags: typo3, tx-news

We are migrating a TYPO3 4.7.14 site with news 1.4.0 to TYPO3 7.6.28 with news 6.3.0.

When we started all news are migrated and are ok on the new server.
But in the time after the news migration some news are added to the old site and now they must be migrated to the new server.

How could this be done?

A t3d Export / Import don't work.

The news are containing a lot of content elements, so it would be an incredible amount of work to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise to make the whole migration-process new, perhaps only with the news-pages, news-plugins (content-elements saved in the table tt_content with the list_type tx_news or resembling) and news-records.
Problem is primary the update to version 6.2 of TYPO3 as the FAL (file abstraction layer) was introduced and all media-files in the news are getting lost if the corresponding update is not done properly.
Keep in mind that you've to care about one setting in file-storage records (usually for the `fileadmin`-folder): the checkbox that case-sensitive filenames are allowed. Else a mess is predictable and much additional work too.
If you do it like I proposed only for the news-records and related records, you've to export and import also the tables starting with `sys_file`, but keep in mind that you really import only then in the upper version instead overwriting the whole table, as there might be still other media-files.